# How can I echo a command in a batch file without executing it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I want to echo this text:cd %~dp0 unchanged to my text file.

but when I run:

```
echo cd %~dp0>new_file.txt
```

It stores the result of the cd command in the text file.

Since double quotes dont work, how can i echo this without executing the command cd?

Answer (score 2):

In batch, you escape `%` by adding a second `%` in front of it.

```
echo cd %%~dp0>new_file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

If all you are doing is trying to save a current directory (where your batch file is) to a text file just run this.

```
cd>new_file.txt
```

Comment: The current working directory and the parent directory of the batch file are two totally different things…